# How can I fix incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'void *'

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I kept trying but I get this message 'warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
'int' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
node2->data = NULL;

I got this code from the lecture so I'm sure that some(or most of) compilers or computers are okay with compiling this code, but mine doesn't work.
I use mac os and visual studio code, and it seems that NULL causes Segmentation fault: 11 in my case.
How am I supposed to fix this?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h> // malloc
    typedef struct Node
    {   
        struct Node *next;
        int data;
    } Node;
    Node *head;
    void freeAll(Node *root)
        {
            Node *cur = head->next;
            while(cur != NULL)
            {
                Node *next = cur->next;
                free(cur);
                cur = next;
            }
        }
    int main(void)
    {
        head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        Node *node1 = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node1->data = 1;
        Node *node2 = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node2->data = 2;
        head->next = node1;
        node1->next = node2;
        node2->data = NULL;
        Node *cur = head->next;
        while (cur != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", cur->data);
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why try to store `NULL` in an int? If you want zero, assign `0`.

Comment: do you want to write C or C++? Your code looks like C

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mre]. You could have demonstrated this problem with the single line: `int n = NULL;`

Comment: And no, it's not this that's causing a segfault. Use a debugger to find which line that's causing it.

Comment: `node2->data = NULL;` is nonsense. Did you mean `node2->next = NULL`?

Comment: I use C and it's just that the codes were from the lecture so I followed to write NULL instead of 0. I think this is just to notify that the end of the linked list array is null but I'm not sure if it's okay to just write 0 for that

Comment: @hyun It is okay to write `NULL` for that.  But you meant to assign to `node2->next`, not `node2->data`.  (Probably a simple typo.)

Comment: @hyun no, it's because `NULL` is a _ pointer_ and node2->data is an `int`. You can't mix them.

Comment: oh that's actually right gotta fix that thank you

Comment: and can I ask you one more question; sometimes I can't use nullptr in my linux so I gotta use NULL instead. Is there any ways to use all those expressions without caring much about the environment that I'm coding?

Comment: `nullptr` is C++, don't mix these two langages, they are very different

Comment: @SteveSummit It's well defined to write NULL in that situation, but I would not say that it's ok, because it really gives the impression of someone who does not know what they're doing.

Comment: I was using nullptr for C++ but in some cases it just didn't work on my linux compiler so- Anyways thank

Comment: @SteveSummit oh.. I see thank you

Comment: @hyun If you CAN use `nullptr`, then you're compiling with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler. If that's what you want, go for it, but it may have unexpected effects.

Comment: @hyun if `nullptr` doesn't work with C++, then either your C++ compiler is broken or you're doing wrong something else.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, I agree that it's wrong. I'm just saying that it's well defined and does not invoke UB.

Comment: @SteveSummit yes of course, I think I misunderstood something. Deleting my comments.

Comment: @klutt *gives the impression of someone who does not know what they're doing* Please explain.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Aha.. get that thanks :)

Comment: @Jabberwocky `(void*)NULL` no NULL is `(void *)0` or just zero.

Comment: @SteveSummit Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing. I'm talking about something like `int x=NULL;` and I say that this is well defined, but wrong according to best practices. Do you agree?

Comment: @klutt I agree.  But we are not talking about the same thing. When you said "It's well defined to write NULL in that situation", you were not talking about the same situation I was.

Comment: Let's summarize: `node1->next = NULL` is correct. `node1->data = NULL` is incorrect because it assigns a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

```
node2->data = NULL;
```

there is a typo. There shall be

```
node2->next = NULL;
```

Also you forgot to initialize the data member `data` of the `head` node.

```
    head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    //...
    head->next = node1;
```

It is not a good approach to define a dummy head node.

It would be much better to write a function that inserts new nodes in the list instead of "manually" to create nodes.

Pay attention to that the function `freeAll` can invoke undefined behavior because in general the pointer `head` can be equal to `NULL`. In this case there is an attempt to use a null pointer to access memory in this statement.

```
        Node *cur = head->next;
```

Also the parameter `root` is not used in the function. If your list is based on the global variable `head` (that is a bad idea) then the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
    void freeAll( void )
    {
        while( head != NULL )
        {
            Node *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
    }
```

A more general function that does not depend on a global variable can be defined the following way

```
    void freeAll( Node **head )
    {
        while( *head != NULL )
        {
            Node *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
    }
```

and called like

```
freeAll( &head );
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the list can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{   
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;

int push_back( Node **head, int data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->data = data;
        
        while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;
        
        *head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void freeAll( Node **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        Node *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

void display( const Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_back( &head, i + 1 );
    }
    
    display( head );
    
    freeAll( &head );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you assign `NULL` which is a pointer value into `int` at `node2->data=NULL`.

Comment: This is the reason for the warning, and is without a doubt a bug. This assignment won't by itself cause a segfault though. The reason for that may be related however.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is not the problem. Problem is that the last element of the linked list does not terminate the list. Its `next` member is not assigned and hold undetermined value.

```
        node1->next = node2;
        node2->data = NULL;   <<==== Error is here
        Node *cur = head->next;
        while (cur != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", cur->data);
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

You do not terminate the linked list with NULL. It is probably a typo it has to be

```
        node1->next = node2;
        node2->next = NULL;
        Node *cur = head->next;
        while (cur != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", cur->data);
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/coYbG6

Comment: int the link is OK